# Should I put external header in .h file or .cpp file?

Tags: c++, header-files

Let say I have a function defined in `foo.h`:

```
#pragma once 
#include <vector>
#include <string>
void foo(std::vector<std:string> input);
```

and In in the implementation file `foo.cpp` I need to use another library (say `std::map`)  for implementing the function foo.

```
void foo(std::vector<std:string> input){
...
std::map ...
...
}
```

Note that `std:map` is not needed in the declaration and it is only implementation specific.

Should I put `#include <map>` in the `foo.h` or `foo.cpp` file?

I know the code will compile for both cases, I am wondering what is a good practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the include in the source file where it is needed.

Putting it in the header would needlessly cause all users of the header to also include `<map>` regardless of whether they need it or not.

For trivial projects this is irrelevant, but for large projects it matters since pointless includes increase compilation time and increase the risk of name collisions.

Answer (score 3):

Be *laconic*, and provide only what is really needed.

Otherwise, in a real large project, you will end up with a bunch of header files, that everyone is afraid to touch, because it might be needed after all.

Moreover, it will make everyone else in the project also include the map library, which is an unneeded overhead (increased compilation time and/or increased danger of name overlapings).